# Axon4 - Standard exception handling mechanism

Tags: exception, axon

What is standard exception handling mechanism for Axon4 ?
Addiotnaally - how do you ensure that if exception occours during one of the event in Saga (in between state), previous states gets rolled back ?

Any example would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a broad question you're asking here Prashant, with a couple of answers to it. Additionally, your asking two questions, one being what the exception handling approach is and two how to deal with exceptions in Sagas.

So, as you're talking about Sagas and events, I am going to take the stance that you want to know the exception handling process around events. Let me first answer your first question here.
As you might have read in the Reference Guide, Axon uses what's called an `EventProcessor` as the technical mechanism to get events to your 'event handling components' **and** Saga instances.

The `EventProcessors` allow two different levels of exception handling:
 1. When an exception occurs in the `@EventHandler`/`@SagaEventHandler` annotated function, this can be caught in the `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler`.
 2. When an exception occurs in the `EventProcessor`, this can be caught in the `ErrorHandler`.

Both of these can be set in Axon 4 by dealing with the `EventProcessingConfigurer` and calling their respective register functions, which allow you to set a global default or adjust these per Event Processor.
The defaults are respectively the `LoggingErrorHandler` and the `PropagatingErrorHandler`.

The second question your asking is about how to rollback state in a Saga when an exception occurs. The suggestion I'd like to give you here is that upon receiving an event, you change the state first **and only after that** will you perform other operations.

Other operations like calling a third party service or publishing a command.
These operations might as you've noticed fail with an exception. This should however not rollback the state of the Saga at all. 
The event *already happened*. The fact that the operation after that failed does not change the fact of that event having occurred.

Thus what I do suggest is that you perform a *compensating action* if such an exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks Steven for elaborate answer !

Comment: No worries Prashant! :-)

Comment: By _compensating action_ , you mean generating compensating event and design event hander  that would rollback the state.Would appreciate if you can provide an example of `ListenerInvocationErrorHandler` and `ErrorHandler' implementation

Comment: An action in messaging world typically is a command. What format or what name that has however wholly depends on the domain you're in.

Comment: @Steven I've been running some tests with Axon. For this point of, let's say, in a third step in a Saga (transaction) I need to compensate and rollback all executed before. Should I stop the current Saga and start a new one? Or just produce sequential actions to rollback each one? I haven't found good explanations/examples about compensation and rollback, that's why I'm asking for. Thank you, btw.

Comment: Good question @rodrigocprates, but I think it warrants it's own question instead of landing in the comment section here. Would you mind creating a dedicated request on StackOverflow? I am actively tracing issues with the `axon` tag, so tagging it as such would make it so that I'll find it (eventually).